# Getting drag and drop to work in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I want to displayan alert box showing the source of images that are dragged into the #dropzone.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/53/Arsenal_FC.svg" alt="arsenal">
<div id="dropzone"></div>

<script>
var drop = document.getElementById(‘dropzone’);

drop.ondrop = function (event) {
   window.alert(event.dataTransfer.getData(‘Text’));
   return false;
};

drop.ondragover = function () { return false; };
drop.ondragenter = function () { return false; };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few Ideas:

1. It seems that you have copied this code from some website, without correcting quotes. `‘dropzone’` should be `'dropzone'`
2. Div without content is practically invisible. Do you have any css style for height and width?
3. To get dropped file name you should use something like `event.dataTransfer.files[0].fileName`

Comment: Yeah I realised that after I typed it out myself, `!==', the div has a style

Answer (score 2):

Most web browsers requires one to prevent default action on *dragenter* and *dragover* to be able to catch drop event.

```
drop.ondragover = function (ev) { 
  ev.preventDefault();
  return false; 
};
drop.ondragenter = function (ev) { 
  ev.preventDefault();
  return false; 
};
```